# Pythonで検索するとニシキヘビが出てくる

Tags: python

このような質問はすべきではないかもしれませんが、Pythonに関する情報を得ようと検索すると、必ずニシキヘビの写真が出てきます。

知り合いのSEは毎回我慢しているといいます。
ブラウザ設定でニシキヘビが出てくるのを回避する方法はありますか？

**環境:**

- Windows10 + Edge
- Android + Google Chrome

#### 検索結果の表示例

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: OSとブラウザは何ですか？

Comment: 下記の組み合わせで使っています。
いずれでも出てきます。

windows10+Edge
Android+Google chrome

Comment: 手元（windows+chrome）では広告出なかったです。履歴とか色々削除しても同じ検索結果となりますか？（自宅でも会社でもPython関連色々検索しますが画像が表示されて困ったことはありません）

Comment: OSの再インストールもやりましたが結果は同じでした。

Comment: 会社の環境、自宅でも両方同じです。

Comment: 参考: [Here's how you can get rid of search history held in Google's servers](https://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/technology/heres-how-you-can-get-rid-of-search-history-held-in-googles-servers/article33029685.ece)

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただ、検索履歴は関係なく、googleのアカウント変えてもダメなのです。

Comment: ただ、1つ分かったのは、OSの言語設定を英語に変えると、ヘビの写真は出てこなくなります。Windows, android共に状況の変化は同じでした。

Comment: 英語環境でも日本語入力はできるので、当面これで運用したいと思います。

Comment: OSとかブラウザの個人情報送信とかお勧めコンテンツ表示とかの有無設定を変更してみてはどうでしょう？[【Windows 10】プライバシー設定を見直して個人情報の送信を止める](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/1904/04/news021.html), [Microsoft Edge、閲覧データ、およびプライバシー](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/bb8174ba-9d73-dcf2-9b4a-c582b4e640dd)

Comment: @Bonjour そうなりますと、パーソナライズド検索をオフ(query parameter `pws=0` を追加)にして検索してみるとどうなりますでしょうか？ [「python コンストラクタ」で検索](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=python+%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%a9%e3%82%af%e3%82%bf&hl=ja&lr=lang_ja&pws=0)

Comment: 広告と表示されている位置から右に行くとグレーの丸に `i` のアイコンがあるかと思いますが、ここをクリックすると「無関係/不快な広告 」等で報告ができると思います。

Comment: 提案いただいた設定の変更やクエリを試してもニシキヘビ出てきます。

Comment: 最近分かったのですが、"python"と入れなくても、"numpy"のキーワード検索でもほとんどがヘビの写真や情報が出てくるだけで、数値計算のページがごくわずかでした。。。

Answer (score 3):

Pythonは錦蛇(ニシキヘビ)科を表す英語なので、"Python"でニシキヘビが検索されるのは、致し方ない事だと思います。

検索語を"Python"ではなく、"Python programing"、"Python 言語"等、プログラミング言語のPythonであることを意味する検索語にするととニシキヘビの画像を回避できませんか？